# Missing Dependency in dependent project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an android project with following structure:

```
-- Calendar
------app (app module)
----------build.gradle (module level)
------build.gradle (project level)
------Commons(A common project which i reuse across various projects)
----------common (common module in Commons project)
-------------build.gradle (for only common module level)
----------build.gradle(for Commons Project)
```

Now the problem is that if I compile Commons, deploy it to bintray and then use it as `implementation 'com.amitkma.Commons:common:1.0.0'` in app module, all the dependencies (which are implemented in common build.gradle) is available to use in app module also. But if I use it like following 
`implementation project(:Commons:common)`, only dependencies provided using `api` is available to use.

I want to know what is the difference between `api` and `implementation` with respect to module is compiled or used directly like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. The separation of `api` and `implementation` when declaring dependencies. In short dependencies in the `implementation` scope are only visible at *runtime* because they are an *implementation* detail. Such libraries will use the `runtime` scope in their published Maven metadata. More information in [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation)
2. Before Gradle 5.0, the Maven metadata scopes `compile` and `runtime` were mixed by Gradle and thus all `runtime` dependencies did appear on the compile classpath. Gradle 5 [changes this](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html#rel5.0:pom_compile_runtime_separation)

So when you publish your component, the limitation of Gradle 4.x means that your `common` dependencies are available to `app`. Note that moving to Gradle 5 will cause a breakage there, as documented.
And when you use the project directly, the separation is properly enforced.

The fix is to simply promote dependencies *that are part of the common api* to the `api` configuration in `common` and for the runtime ones, declare them in `app` as after all they are directly required by it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.