# Gradle Android dependency resolution, differences between local module and maven lib

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle

I made a test project to verify the issue.

1. Opening Android Studio
2. I created a new basic project. Its main module was called `app`.
3. I added a library module, called `libA`.
4. In `libA`, I added a dependency to Gson with 
    `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'` 
    and added a single class `ClassA` with a single method using `Gson`.
5. In `app`, I added a dependency to `libA` with 
   `implementation project(path: ':liba')` 
    In MainActivity, I used the class from `libA`, without problem. **`Gson` is unreachable, from the main activity, as expected**.
6. I published into maven local the lib a using `maven-publish` plugin with 
   `./gradlew :liba:publishMsdkPublicationToMavenLocal`
7. I've switched the import from the one above to 
    `implementation "com.ndefiorenze:lib-a:1.0.0"`
   Now I can continue to use the class defined in libA without problems **but I also have access to Gson** and in the Main Activity I can do

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    Log.d("classA", new Gson().toJson(list));
```

How can I prevent Gson from being exposed in the `app` when `liba` is on maven?

---

Here some sources:

```
public class ClassA {

    public void fooA(){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("a");
        Log.d("classA", new Gson().toJson(list));
    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ClassA().fooA()
    }
}
```

liba build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        msdk(MavenPublication) {

            groupId 'com.ndefiorenze'
            artifactId 'lib-a'
            version "1.0.0"
            artifact(bundleReleaseAar)
            pom.withXml {
                def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')
                configurations.implementation.allDependencies.each {
                    if(it.group != null && (it.name != null || "unspecified" == it.name) && it.version != null) {
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', it.version)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository"
        }
    }
}
```

application build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ndefiorenze.dependencyagain"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation project(path: ':liba')
//    implementation "com.ndefiorenze:lib-a:1.0.0"
}
```

project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: See this answer that references a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147067/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, if I read that answer correctly, it's about _including_ a missing dependency rather than _excluding_ one.  If I understand the question, he wants to limit access to Gson to liba, and not see it in app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the recent changes to gradle myself, but if I read [this article](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/managing_transitive_dependencies.html) correctly, you want to exclude a transitive dependency as illustrated.

```
dependencies {
    implementation('log4j:log4j:1.2.15') {
        exclude group: 'javax.jms', module: 'jms'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jdmk', module: 'jmxtools'
        exclude group: 'com.sun.jmx', module: 'jmxri'
    } }
```

So in your application build file;

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation project(path: ':liba'){
       exclude group: 'com.google.code.gson', module:'gson'
   }
```

should prevent Gson from being accessible from app.